# React.forwardRef - get value from child component

Tags: reactjs

Imagine we have code like this:

```
const InputComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // I need to access ref.current?.value... here
  return <input ref={ref} {...props} />
})

const Parent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef()


  return <InputComponent ref={ref} />
}
```

This technique seems to be impossible? the  `typeof ref` in `InputComponent` is a function but cannot be called.
Can I access the `ref.current.value` from `InputComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Except a typo your code should work, the only thing to notice that you don't have the ref **on first render** therefore the optional chaining `current?.value`.

And because its a ref, changing the input value does not trigger a render, so to debug its value you need manually trigger it.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

const InputComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  console.log(ref.current?.value);
  return <input ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [, render] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);

  return (
    <>
      <InputComponent ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={render}>trigger render to see ref value</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}
```

[image: Edit objective-bouman-e75or]